# HTMLタグの属性で非ASCII文字のURLエスケープは必要か

Tags: html, encoding

例えば、ネット上のサイトに`https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/パーセントエンコーディング`というページへのリンクを設けるとき、`<a>`タグのhref属性はどのように記述すれば良いのでしょうか。パーセントエンコーディングすれば確実に世界中からアクセスすることができますが、リンクしようとしているURLはさまざまな形式なので簡単にエンコードできません（既存のエスケープ関数だと`:`や`/`などエンコードしたくないものまで処理するので自作するしかなさそうですが、他にどんな記号をエンコードすべきでないかまだよくわからないのです）。

そこで、

```
<a href='https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/パーセントエンコーディング'>ここをクリック</a>
```

のようにパーセントエンコーディングしないリンクがどれほど通用するか、教えてください。曖昧な質問で申し訳ありませんが、知りたいのはUTF-8形式のテキストファイルを扱えるブラウザなら必ずリンクを開けるとかそういうことです。

Comment: 質問のリンク先にあるように、RFC3986に基づけば、一般に日本語を含むマルチバイト文字が含まれるURLは不正です。このエスケープ処理は各種言語に`urlencode`にあたる関数がありますし、あるいは手動でページを作成するならばこちらも`urlencode`で探せばオンラインのツールがいくらでもあります。他方、日本で使用されている最近のメジャーなブラウザはこれらリンクを読めてしまいます。これはウェブブラウザが厳格な検証ツールではなく、単なる閲覧ソフトであり利便性を考慮しての実装でしょう。

Comment: その「パーセントエンコーディングしないリンク」とは、厳密にはURLではなくIRIと呼びます。html4ではダメでしたが、html5ではIRIを使えるようになりました。ですのでhtml5で記述され、ブラウザがhtml5をサポートする限り問題ないと言えます。IDNの可能性も考慮すると、属性値のパースが必須なので単純にエスケープしようとしないことです。 https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/urls.html#parsing-urls